# NullPointerException in Listview with AsyncTask

Tags: android, listview, android-asynctask, nullpointerexception

I am writing a module that fetch some content from server in background and show on listview. my code is

```
public class ContentList extends Activity {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        String contentURL = getIntent().getExtras().getString("contentURL);

        new Retreivecontent().execute(contentURL );

    } 

    class Retreivecontent extends AsyncTask<String, Void, List<String>>{

        @Override
        protected List<String> doInBackground(String... urls) {
            Document document = null;
            List<String> content = new ArrayList<String>();
            Log.d("$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$", urls[0]);
            try {
                document = Jsoup.connect(urls[0]).get();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            Elements allList = document.getElementsByTag("p");
            for (Element element : allList) {
                String poem = element.select("p:has(br)").text();
                if(!poem.equals("")){
                    content.add(poem);
                }

            }

            return content;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(List<String> result) {
            Log.d("$################", result.toString());
            final ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.contentList);
            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(contentList.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, result);
            listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        }
    }

}
```

Log is printing result properly means i am getting result from server. ListView id is correct. I am not getting why it is giving null pointer exception. Can any one explain me other reason fro the same error?

Error log is

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.app.ranjeish.ContentList$RetreiveContent.onPostExecute(ContentList.java:63)
at com.app.ranjeish.ContentList$RetreiveContent.onPostExecute(ContentList.java:1)
at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:631)
at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:644)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

The xml code for list view is

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" >

    </ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: post the stacktrace and some more relevant code

Comment: LogCat, plus the code of ListView in XML?

Comment: It is not difficult just debug your code properly.

Comment: final ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.List); probably does not found a list and thus its null and thus listView.setAdapter(adapter); throws NPE

Comment: I guess its `listView.setAdapter(adapter);`

Comment: does doInBackground return  something != null ?

Comment: it is returning data that i want

Comment: @LalitChattar post the full activity code and the nsame of the xml

Comment: can you able to print this line Log.d("$################", result.toString());

Comment: yes i am able to print

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing `setContentView` for the activity

```
ListView listview;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_content); // set layout to activity
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list) // id is list
```

And Change this

```
 ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(contentList.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, result);
```

To

```
 ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(ContentList.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, result);
 // C in caps
```

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same problem.

The thing is that you have to assign the `listview` and the `adapter` outside of the task and prior to calling it, as well as setting the adapter.

Once done (usually in the `onActivityCreated` if you use fragments), you can call your asynctask and call only `yourAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` in the `onPostExecute`.

In the doInBackground you update the adatper directly and, as said before, you only call `yourAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` when the task is finished, in the `onPostExecute`.

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    mListView = (ListView) getView().findViewById(R.id.your_listview);
    mAdapter = new ResultVerAdapter(getActivity(), R.id.your_listview, R.layout.row_layout, mListItems);
    mListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    ...
    new YourAsyncTask().execute();
}

// your_types : i.e <Void, Integer, Integer>
private class YourAsyncTask extends AsyncTask< your_types > {
    protected Integer doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        ...
        mListItems.add(your_item_type);
        ...
    }
    ...
    protected void onPostExecute(Integer result) {
        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();    
    }
}
```